# HTML5 animation - Canvas or DOM?

Tags: html, animation, html5-canvas

I'm wondering what would be the most efficient solution to animate sprites(images) moving on a fixed background : use DOM elements with absolute positioning or animate them on a canvas (with drawImage and clearRect) ?

The advantage I see in the first option is I don't have to worry about erasing old position before drawing the new one. Does it make sense ?

Do you see any other good alternative ?

Thanks

**Edit:** I want to focus on mobile devices. Does it make a big difference in terms of HTML5 support?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266416/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-canvas-vs-dom-in-javascript-game-devel

Comment: Also depends on which browsers you have to support.

Comment: I want to focus on mobile devices. Does it make a big difference in terms of HTML5 support ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some "pro" canvas arguments:

- The nice fact about canvas is that can be 2D accelerated and you can obtain high fps.
- Also the problem with DOM is that you are limited to rectangle shape only.
- All modern browsers have nice canvas support so if you are not limited by legacy system it makes more sense to use canvas

Comment: in the DOM .. you are not just limited to rectange shapes. With CSS shapes you can make Circles and other types of shapes.. http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ .. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/ .. and you can also use images too.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 Canvas is relativelly new, if there are only few sprites, you should use DOM elements, it will work on most browsers. Don't forget, some older MSIEs can't display transparent PNGs, only GIFs (I don't remember the version), there are lot of folks with outdated browsers.

Also a good alternative is not to do, and also don't use animgifs on your website; be careful with flying-around things, less is more.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements don't require you to use Canvas, use DOM elements and absolute positioning as it will work on older browsers.